How to force curl to only use the certificates that I specify to validate TLS?
I want to test that I can connect to a domain using only a specific set of certificates (stored as a set of PEM files).
However it seems like curl is not ignoring the built-in trusted certificates when I use the --cacert and --capath options. So even this works, when I'd like it to fail: curl --cacert AmazonRootCA4.pem https://google.com
What's the easiest way to do this? I don't need to stick with curl

are you running on Windows or MacOS? It seems like those will always use the OS certificate store.
https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html - heading "Certificate Verification with Schannel and Secure Transport"

macOS and Linux

This works:
openssl s_client -CAfile /path/to/cert.pem -verify_return_error -no-CApath -verify 5 -connect mydomain.com:443 | grep 'Verify return code'

Note that if you want to use -CApath for multiple PEMs, then you need to run openssl rehash on the directory!

If you specify only -CAfile it also uses the default CApath IF that is valid, which depends on your build and installation; if so, to prevent that add -no-CApath (except long-obsolete versions 0.9.x and 1.0.x)
